# Texturing a makehuman mesh after sculpt

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, makehuman

I wanted to re-sculpt my (mhx2) mesh from Makehuman. After that, I noticed that some faces haven't texture. It could be logical I guess.

But I can't bring back or paint these faces parts with texture.

I've tried to unwrap, re-load the image texture or paint but that doesn't work. Where is my mistake and how can I do ?
Thanks for help !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to risk some down votes and be harsh but honest with you. But this is how I would answer this to a friend. I think the mistake is that you are rushing too much. I would recommend taking it slower. MakeHuman is a great tool, but it is not magic, you cannot skip learning the basics of 3d before using it. My honest recommendation would be to forget about this for now and to spend a bit more time learning more about modelling, UV mapping, textures and materials, functions and workflows of the software. Maybe try modeling a simple face without too much detail from scratch, learn to UV unwrap it and make a basic texture and material for it yourself. It doesn't need to be perfect, but you will get a better understanding on what you can and cannot do with the software during this experience. Do not be afraid to do and redo and redo and redo the same things again and again until you get them right. Recognize when it is frustrating and know that frustration can be a part of this process and is OK. It usually means that you are learning.

At the moment the problem would be hard to fix for an experienced 3d artist. This is the point where one should start from the beginning and concentrate on doing it right from the start instead of trying to fix it. I am not trying to be rude here - everything is fine with the situation, it happens, not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand your point ! It's so long to learn... haha ^^

Answer (score 0):

If the model already has a texture, then avoid using dyntopo sculpt as this will introduce triangles not unwrapped to the texture.

If the model is needing to be sculpted, then use a multiresolution modifier and regular sculpting so that the texture still is present for the face subdivision and will most likely still fit the model. This isn't the best way to work, however, since the texture can be distorted based on how deep the changes are to the surface normal of the model.

Texturing is best done after the modeling is finished normally.